# How can I print list in dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have following string and I want to print the list objects:

```
{u'categories': [u'Food', u'Grocery']}
```

I used following ode but does not work:

```
d = {u'categories': [u'Food', u'Grocery']}                        
print "Categories: " + d['categories']                     
print "Categories: " + d['categories[0]']
```

Thank you!

Comment: Voting to close as too localized

Comment: [diveintopython](http://www.diveintopython.net/toc/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> d = {u'categories': [u'Food', u'Grocery']}
>>> print "Categories: " + ', '.join(d['categories'])
Categories: Food, Grocery
>>> print "Categories: " + d['categories'][0]
Categories: Food
```

Comment: is it same as printing float and integer in dictionary ?

Comment: @Mahdi No, they need to be converted to `str` for printing. Example: `print "Numbers: " + ', '.join(map(str, d['numbers']))`. I'm not sure exactly how you need this formatted since you did not specify it in the question. Try some of these options out for yourself

Comment: @Mahdi That's really a different question, if you want an answer to it you will have to ask it separately or at least update your current question with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting to print categories followed by the name of each category then:

```
for category in your_dict['categories']:
    print 'Categories:', category
```

Comment: @Mahdi then I can assume that jamylak's answer is closer to what you wish to achieve then...

Comment: @Mahdi Also prints the other items on different lines. If you add a trailing comma `print 'Categories:', category, `  it will print them on one line, space separated

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in your_dict.iteritems():
    for item in v:
        print k, ":", item
```